# How to alternately send data using 2 trackbars for one serialport in VB.Net 2012

Tags: vb.net, arduino

I am trying to control voltage and frequency in my inverter project output. But i am facing problems with the VB.Net design. But i can't get it works. You can see at the image, i am using 2 radio button. My goal is when radiobutton1 checked, then trackbar1 sends data to arduino, the same for radiobutton2 and trackbar2 (but when radiobutton2 sends the data, trackbar1 is terminated). And also, i don't know how to connect my voltage and frequency control code with VB.Net. Could anyone help me, please?

Here's my current arduino code

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
int k=0;

int x=0;
int y=0;
int z=0;

int OK=0;
int OK1=0;
int OK2=0;
int OK3=0;
int OK4=0;

int sinPWM[]={0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29,31,32,33,34,36,37,38,39,40,42,43,44,45,47,48,49,50,52,53,54,55,56,
              58,59,60,61,62,64,65,66,67,68,70,71,72,73,74,76,77,78,79,80,82,83,84,85,86,87,89,90,91,92,93,94,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,104,105,106,
              107,108,109,110,111,112,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,
              142,143,144,145,147,148,149,150,151,152,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,171,172,173,
              174,175,176,177,178,179,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,185,186,187,188,189,189,190,191,192,193,193,194,195,196,197,197,198,199,200,200,
              201,202,203,203,204,205,205,206,207,208,208,209,210,210,211,212,212,213,214,214,215,215,216,217,217,218,219,219,220,220,221,221,222,
              223,223,224,224,225,225,226,226,227,227,228,228,229,229,230,230,231,231,232,232,233,233,234,234,234,235,235,236,236,237,237,237,238,
              238,238,239,239,240,240,240,241,241,241,241,242,242,242,243,243,243,244,244,244,244,245,245,245,245,246,246,246,246,246,247,247,247,
              247,247,247,248,248,248,248,248,248,248,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,
              249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,249,248,248,248,248,248,248,248,247,247,247,247,247,247,246,246,246,246,246,245,245,
              245,245,244,244,244,244,243,243,243,242,242,242,241,241,241,241,240,240,240,239,239,238,238,238,237,237,237,236,236,235,235,234,234,
              234,233,233,232,232,231,231,230,230,229,229,228,228,227,227,226,226,225,225,224,224,223,223,222,221,221,220,220,219,219,218,217,217,
              216,215,215,214,214,213,212,212,211,210,210,209,208,208,207,206,205,205,204,203,203,202,201,200,200,199,198,197,197,196,195,194,193,
              193,192,191,190,189,189,188,187,186,185,185,184,183,182,181,180,179,179,178,177,176,175,174,173,172,171,171,170,169,168,167,166,165,
              164,163,162,161,160,159,158,157,156,155,154,153,152,152,151,150,149,148,147,145,144,143,142,141,140,139,138,137,136,135,134,133,132,
              131,130,129,128,127,126,125,123,122,121,120,119,118,117,116,115,114,112,111,110,109,108,107,106,105,104,102,101,100,99,98,97,96,94,
              93,92,91,90,89,87,86,85,84,83,82,80,79,78,77,76,74,73,72,71,70,68,67,66,65,64,62,61,60,59,58,56,55,54,53,52,50,49,48,47,45,44,43,42,
              40,39,38,37,36,34,33,32,31,29,28,27,26,24,23,22,21,19,18,17,16,14,13,12,11,9,8,7,6,4,3,2,1,0};

#define toggle 7
int sw;
int AnalogDataVolt;
int nilaiVB;

int potvolt = A1; //Pengatur Tegangan
int potfreq = A2; //Pengatur Frequency

float potvoltval;
float potfreqval;

float A;
float F;

String inputString = "";         // a String to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete
int val = 0;

int Volt = 0;
int Freq = 0;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
inputString.reserve(200);

pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
pinMode(5,OUTPUT);

cli();// stop interrupts
TCCR0A=0;//reset nilai
TCCR0B=0;//reset nilai
TCNT0=0;//reset nilai
//0b : menulis bits dalam binary
TCCR0A=0b10100001;//phase correct pwm mode
TCCR0B=0b00000001; //tidak ada prescaler

TCCR2A=0;//reset nilai
TCCR2B=0;//reset nilai
TCNT2=0;//reset nilai
//0b : menulis bits dalam binary
TCCR2A=0b10100001;//phase correct pwm mode
TCCR2B=0b00000001; //tidak ada prescaler

TCCR3A=0;//reset nilai
TCCR3B=0;//reset nilai
TCNT3=0;//reset nilai
//0b  : menulis bits dalam binary
TCCR3A=0b10100001;//phase correct pwm mode
TCCR3B=0b00000001; //tidak ada prescaler

TCCR1A=0;//reset nilai
TCCR1B=0;//reset nilai
TCNT1=0;//reset nilai
OCR1A=509;// compare match value
TCCR1B=0b00001001; //WGM12 bit is 1 for CTC mode and no prescaler

TIMSK1 |=(1 << OCIE1A);// memulai interrupts

sei();//stop interrupts
}
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){// interrupt mulai ketika timer 1 cocok dengan OCR1A 
if(i>629 && OK==0){// nilai akhir dari sample untuk pin 13
i=0;// mulai dari nilai awal sample
OK=1;//mengaktifkan pin 4
}
if(i>629 && OK==1){// nilai akhir dari sample untuk pin 4
i=0;//mulai dari nilai awal sample
OK=0;//mengaktifkan pin 13
}
x=round(A*sinPWM[i]);// nilai x berasal dari sample dan i berindex 0
i=i+F;// ke posisi selanjutnya dari sample
if(OK==0){
OCR0B=0;//pin 4 0
OCR0A=x;//pin 13 memulai pembacaan sample
}
if(OK==1){
OCR0A=0;//pin 13 0
OCR0B=x;//pin 4 memulai pembacaan sample
}

if ((i>=418) || OK1==1){//jika nilai i mencapai 209, maka phase kedua akan dimulai
OK1=1;//mempertahankan if function
if(j>629 && OK2==0){// nilai akhir dari sample untuk pin 10
j=0;// mulai dari nilai awal sample
OK2=1;//mengaktifkan pin 9
}
if(j>629 && OK2==1){// nilai akhir dari sample untuk pin 9
j=0;//mulai dari nilai awal sample
OK2=0;//mengaktifkan pin 10
}
y=round(A*sinPWM[j]);// nilai y berasal dari sample dan i berindex 0
j=j+F;// ke posisi selanjutnya dari sample
if(OK2==0){
OCR2B=0;//pin 9 0
OCR2A=y;//pin 10 memulai pembacaan sample
}
if(OK2==1){
OCR2A=0;//pin 10 0
OCR2B=y;//pin 9 memulai pembacaan sample
}
}
if ((j>=418) || OK3==1){//jika nilai j mencapai 209, maka phase ketiga akan dimulai
OK3=1;//mempertahankan if function
if(k>629 && OK4==0){// nilai akhir dari sample untuk pin 5
k=0;// mulai dari nilai awal sample
OK4=1;//mengaktifkan pin 2
}
if(k>629 && OK4==1){// nilai akhir dari sample untuk pin 2
k=0;//mulai dari nilai awal sample
OK4=0;//mengaktifkan pin 5
}
z=round(A*sinPWM[k]);// nilai z berasal dari sample dan i berindex 0
k=k+F;// ke posisi selanjutnya dari sample
if(OK4==0){
OCR3B=0;//pin 2 0
OCR3A=z;//pin 5 memulai pembacaan sample
}
if(OK4==1){
OCR3A=0;//pin 5 0
OCR3B=z;//pin 2 memulai pembacaan sample
}
}
}
void loop() {  
sw = digitalRead(toggle);

    potvoltval= analogRead(AnalogDataVolt);
    A= potvoltval/1023;

    potfreqval= analogRead(potfreq);
    F= map(potfreqval,1023,0,0,50);

    if (sw == 1){ //    vb
    if (stringComplete) {
    val = inputString.toInt();
    AnalogDataVolt = nilaiVB;
    nilaiVB = map(val, 0, 255, 0, 1023);
    Serial.println(val);
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;}
    }
    else
    AnalogDataVolt = analogRead(potvolt); //    pot
  }
}

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag so the main loop can
    // do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my VB.Net code

```
    Public Class Form1
    Sub Serial()
        Me.CenterToParent()
        SerialPort1.PortName = "COM4"
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
        SerialPort1.Open()
        Timer1.Start()
        SerialPort1.Write(TrackBar2.Value & Chr(10))
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.CenterToParent()
        SerialPort1.PortName = "COM4"
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
        SerialPort1.Open()
        Timer1.Start()
        SerialPort1.Write(TrackBar1.Value & Chr(10))
    End Sub

    Public Sub send_data(ByVal data_kirim As String)
        If SerialPort1.IsOpen() Then
            SerialPort1.Write(data_kirim + Environment.NewLine())
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TrackBar1.Value = 255
        TrackBar2.Value = 255
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TrackBar1.Value = 0
        TrackBar2.Value = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Try
            Dim i As Single = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
            lbl1.Text = "PWM Value : " & i.ToString
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            Call Serial()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```